# Launching a UWP app as the shell

Tags: windows-10, shell, uwp

In the excellent answer to [How do I replace the system shell (explorer.exe) with another process in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1016380/how-do-i-replace-the-system-shell-explorer-exe-with-another-process-in-windows) one provides the path to an executable as the value of a registry key.

Can this be adapted to launch a UWP app? How?

Comment: Why would you not just look into the kiosk mode of Windows?

Comment: Because, @Seth, not everyone is aware this is an expressly supported mode. That's a good answer to the question, and if it had a link to documentation on using kiosk mode it would be a great answer. Pity someone has already voted the question down without saying why. If it's a supported mode then obviously this is something people want to know about.

Comment: There are various questions regarding this already here and also official documentation exists [Set up a kiosk or digital signage on Windows 10 Pro, Enterprise, or Education](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/set-up-a-kiosk-for-windows-10-for-desktop-editions) maybe give it a shot.