# How to disable right click app icon and start on Taskbar in Win10

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, group-policy

When right click [app icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGgY5.png) and [start icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Liasb.png), the list will be shown.

Using "Remove access to the context menus for the taskbar" GPO can disable right click Taskbar Context Menu or using Registry block the right click taskbar function , but this GPO cannot disable right click app icon and start.

So, how to block right click app icon and start icon in taskbar? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For the App Icon, the closest thing i can find is the policy "Do not allow pinning programs to the Taskbar"

If that is not enough, please help me understand why you would want to disable the entire menu.

For the start icon, the only solution i could find (which i recommend you to be careful with) is going to %localappdata%\Microsoft\Windows\WinX

In that folder, move the folders Group1, Group2 and Group3 to a different location. After that the right click start menu will not appear. If you want to switch back, move the folders back to their original location.

You can do the same trick if you want this for all users, if you go to C:\Users\Default\Appdata\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WinX

Comment: Disable entire menu function is an user requirement, so we don't want right click icon on taskbar having any response. Btw, thank you for blocking right click start icon solution.

Comment: @TimothyT.T Are you attempting to prevent users from your program? If so, it might be better to use kiosk mode in Windows 10, see : https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/kiosk-single-app or you can just replace explorer with your own program, see : https://superuser.com/questions/1016380/how-do-i-replace-the-system-shell-explorer-exe-with-another-process-in-windows