# show/hide specific icon on windows notification area with command line

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, taskbar, notification-area

How to make a icon appear/hide on the notification area of taskbar (may be as known as system tray) with command line? Like what I can do with the following UI:

[image: Select which icons appear on the taskbar]

I thought it could be somewhere under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer` or elsewhere but didn't find anything when monitoring registry event `RegSetValue` with *procmon*.

*My intension is to hide a set of icons during work hours while show them later via command line.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the answer from @harrymc will allow you to add and remove programs to the *actual taskbar*, in the context of this question (as illustrated by the screenshot), the word "taskbar" actually refers to Windows's "Notification Area" (previously formally, and now informally, known as the "system tray" or "systray").

And, unfortunately, as stated [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/taskbar-extensions#notification-area):

> **There have been changes to** the notification area that give the user much more control over what icons appear on **the taskbar**. All notification **icons** are now hidden by default and that visibility **cannot be programmatically controlled**.

(emphasis mine)

I found this information on [this MSDN thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/3b257ee7-d9f9-4747-a845-a489a3dc03b7/windows-10-hide-systray-system-icons-registrywin32-api), which happens to be the exact same question OP is asking.

Now, as the question does not explicit this, and the the sake of completion: if the question is about controlling an icon added by the same program that is meant to control it, the [documentation is here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/taskbar#adding-modifying-and-deleting-icons-in-the-notification-area).

One last point: if you don't mind thinking out of the box (and thus, hacking), you might be able to get around this restriction using either of those methods:

- [Intercept](https://stackoverflow.com/a/843799) the `dwMessage` to the [Shell_NotifyIconA function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shell_notifyicona) in the program(s) of which you want to control the icon, using a program of your own making (this may or may not require you to execute the original binary as a child of the program you made).
- [Replace `explorer.exe` by your own binary](https://superuser.com/questions/1016380/how-do-i-replace-the-system-shell-explorer-exe-with-another-process-in-windows/1016381#1016381), that replicates its appearance and features. I know this sounds nuts, but it would fix the issue in the least hacky way.

Comment: I do call it the system tray everyday but I get confused when I take the screenshot. So I used the taskbar in the question. Thanks for the information:) will try to verify it soon

Comment: @Ramhound shocking, indeed. I still can barely drink my tea without spilling ;) Either way, I edited my answer to reflect your remark, and should you need any proof that windows **did indeed** have something formally called the "system tray" or "systray", please [read this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/audio/systray-and-sndvol32). I could not, however, find any "formal" mention of said "action bar", outside of the [`Android.app` namespace](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.app.actionbar)... But if you know where, I'd be happy to learn. Cheers.

Comment: Sorry, action center, autocorrect

Answer (score 2):

The most reliable method I have found is this little command-line tool:
[Pin to Taskbar](http://www.technosys.net/products/utils/pintotaskbar).

To use it in a command line to pin:

```
syspin "path/file.exe" c:5386
```

And to unpin:

```
syspin "path/file.exe" c:5387
```

I tested the program on Windows 10 20H2 and it worked fine with the above
parameters. Other PowerShell scripts that used to be recommended in the past
did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

The registry key you are looking for is `IconStreams` in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\TrayNotify`

I just answered a [duplicate question here](https://superuser.com/questions/1753209/how-to-make-icon-show-up-in-notification-area-of-the-taskbar-from-the-command-li/1806256#1806256)

The gist is that `IconStreams` needs some processing to read and edit since it is ROT-13 encoded and packed into a REG_BINARY.  So you can either:

(1) Save and restore the value as a whole -- or even the whole `TrayNotify` parent container, e.g.:

```
@rem save:
reg export "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\TrayNotify" "TrayNotify1.reg"

@rem restore and restart explorer to re-read the key:
reg import "TrayNotify1.reg"
start /wait TASKKILL /F /IM explorer.exe && start explorer.exe
```

(2) OR change `IconStreams` programmatically.  Most of the code I've found is Powershell:

- [indented-automation/SystemTray.ps1](https://gist.github.com/indented-automation/8035cdbe21ff38ab8eb79bb4be84d2e6)
- [nodgear/Awesome ManageTray.ps1](https://github.com/nodgear/Awesome/blob/c4ae617e114975e6f8c52fb5656c84a1107ab616/%40Resources/Scripts/Batch/ManageTray.ps1)
- [stevencohn/WindowsPowerShell Set-NotifyIcon.ps1](https://github.com/stevencohn/WindowsPowerShell/blob/fd56aec2c8823c7600cba29e38b9913b109fbf9d/Modules/Scripts/Set-NotifyIcon.ps1)

Tim Mintner also has an old 2011 blog post where he [partially reverse engineered the format](https://web.archive.org/web/20221007042903/https://tmintner.wordpress.com/2011/07/08/windows-7-notification-area-automation-falling-back-down-the-binary-registry-rabbit-hole/) of IconStreams

Comment: thanks! this looks promising