# How to make icon show up in notification area of the taskbar FROM THE COMMAND LINE?

Tags: windows, taskbar

I'm trying to script configuration of the notification area on the Windows taskbar.

Windows has a GUI that will do it:

[image]

That puts icons in the notification area, like this:

[image]

How can this be done from the command line (cmd.exe or Powershell)?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i couldn't make this ANY simpler. These are command prompt commands. I am using the filezilla ftp client (https://filezilla-project.org/) as a sample. If you don't have it, download and install it! So you can see it in action and that it in fact works.
to turn an icon off:

REG ADD HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Notifications\Settings\FileZilla.Client.AppID /v Enabled /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f

To turn an icon back on:
REG DELETE HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Notifications\Settings\FileZilla.Client.AppID /v Enabled /f

You can edit these commands for your purposes for anything in your notifications section of the registry by browsing in regedit to:
HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Notifications\Settings\

and replacing this part of my command with the keyname of the notification you want to edit "FileZilla.Client.AppID"

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work for me. This has no effect on notification area icons (that I can tell).

Answer (score 0):

Press and hold or right-click any empty space on the taskbar and select Taskbar settings. Under Taskbar corner icons: Select On for any icons you want to see on the taskbar.

Comment: Thanks, but I need a method that works from the command line (cmd.exe or Powershell), as mentioned in the question..

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full answer but is info I (the OP) received from someone else about the problem - I'm posting this for the benefit of anyone else looking at this question:

> What you want to do is programmatically add an icon to the system
> tray. (I am assuming you want the icon to appear next to the Wifi,
> Battery and Volume icons.) By default the command prompt has not
> access to the system tray. So you would have to use a ps1 file and a
> bat file to execute. Your commands will have to kill explorer and then
> restart it after the registry change. It is doable, but quite
> involving.
>
> But as a general guide, you want your ps1 file to take 2 items,  the
> icon name and the value 2 that is assigned to showing icons and
> notifications. Then it has to change the IconsStream variable in your
> TrayNotification registry key. It's quite involving, but that is the
> general direction you want to head in.
>
> Alternatively, you can use Shell_NotifyIcon and specify the dwMessage
> as NIM_ADD. This approach would require you to know C++ though to work
> with Shell_NotifyIcon.

Also, another thread re the same issue (and also no solution; sorry I didn't find this before posting the new question): [show/hide specific icon on windows notification area with command line](https://superuser.com/questions/1635898/show-hide-specific-icon-on-windows-notification-area-with-command-line?rq=1)

For myself, I think it's too complicated and for now I'm giving up on it.

Someone could probably make a useful shareware or open source command line program to do this (but not me).

Answer (score 0):

Here are two options.  I have successfully tested #1 (reg.exe) but not #2 (powershell) yet:

(1) You can export HKCU's `TrayNotify\IconStreams` key from the registry for each layout you want and then reimport one when you want to switch (and restart explorer).  For example:

(a) setup the systray the way you want, then:

```
reg export "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\TrayNotify" "TrayNotify1.reg"
```

"TrayNotify1.reg" (UTF-16LE BOM) then includes the `IconStream` key which contains your settings.  It also includes other keys you may not need.

(b) setup the systray in the second way you'd like and do the export again but this time to a different file like "TrayNotify2.reg".

(c) to switch back to the first layout, for example:

```
reg import "TrayNotify1.reg"
start /wait TASKKILL /F /IM explorer.exe && start explorer.exe
```

(2) OR you can use these nice [PowerShell functions `indented-automation/SystemTray.ps1`](https://gist.github.com/indented-automation/8035cdbe21ff38ab8eb79bb4be84d2e6) to control the visibility of icons in the system tray, including the ROT13 encoding.  Nota bene: I have not tested this code.

```
# https://gist.github.com/indented-automation/8035cdbe21ff38ab8eb79bb4be84d2e6
# Functions to allow changes to the visibility of icons in the system tray.
# indented-automation/SystemTray.ps1

enum Visibility : byte {
    Default = 0
    Hide    = 1
    Show    = 2
}

function Convert-CaesarCipher {
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS
        Convert a string to and from a Caesar cipher (ROT-13) encoding.
    .DESCRIPTION
        Convert a string to and from a Caesar cipher (ROT-13) encoding.
    #>

    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        # The string to encode or decode.
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
        [string]$String
    )

    process {
        $chars = foreach ($char in $string.ToCharArray()) {
            if ($char -notmatch '[a-z]') {
                $char
                continue
            }

            $decrement = ($char -ge 'A' -and $char -le 'Z' -and $char -gt 'M') -or
                ($char -ge 'a' -and $char -le 'z' -and $char -gt 'm')

            if ($decrement) {
                [int]$char - 13
            } else {
                [int]$char + 13
            }
        }
        [string]::new([char[]]$chars)
    }
}

function Resolve-KnownFolder {
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS
        Resolve GUID known folder values to full paths.
    .DESCRIPTION
        Resolve GUID known folder values to full paths.
    #>

    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        # A path containing a GUID to resolve.
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        [string]$Path
    )

    begin {
        if (-not ('KnownFolder' -as [Type])) {
            Add-Type -TypeDefinition '
            using System;
            using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
            
            internal class UnsafeNativeMethods
            {
                [DllImport("shell32.dll")]
                internal static extern int SHGetKnownFolderPath(
                    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid rfid,
                    uint dwFlags,
                    IntPtr hToken,
                    out IntPtr ppszPath
                );
            }
            
            public class KnownFolder {
                public static string GetPath(Guid guid)
                {
                    IntPtr ppszPath = IntPtr.Zero;
                    UnsafeNativeMethods.SHGetKnownFolderPath(
                        guid,
                        0,
                        IntPtr.Zero,
                        out ppszPath
                    );
                    string path = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(ppszPath);
                    Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(ppszPath);
            
                    return path;
                }
            }
            '
        }
    }
    
    process {
        $pathElements = $Path -split '[\\/]'
        if ($guid = $pathElements[0] -as [Guid]) {
            $pathElements[0] = [KnownFolder]::GetPath($guid)
            $Path = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($pathElements)
        }
        $Path
    }
}

function Get-SystemTrayIcon {
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS
        Get system tray icon visibility.
    
    .DESCRIPTION
        Get system tray icon visibility using the IconStreams value in the registry.
    #>

    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        # The path for the system tray icon. By default app paths are displayed.
        [string]$Path = '*'
    )

    $registryPath = 'HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\TrayNotify'
    $iconStreams = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path $registryPath -Name IconStreams
    # The flag for visibility appears at offset 528
    $systemTrayToggleOffset = 528

    # The iconStreams array has a 20 byte header, followed by 1640 byte records describing each icon.
    for ($i = 20; $i -lt $iconStreams.Count; $i += 1640) {
        # The path is Unicode encoded and null terminated.
        $iconPathBytes = for (($j = 0), ($isChar = $true); $isChar; $j += 2) {
            $left = $iconStreams[$i + $j]
            $right = $iconStreams[$i + $j + 1]

            $isChar = $left -ne 0 -or $right -ne 0
            if ($isChar) {
                $left, $right
            }
        }
        $iconPath = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString([byte[]]$iconPathBytes) | Convert-CaesarCipher

        if ($iconPath -like $Path) {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                PSTypeName = 'IconStreamsRecord'
                Visibility = [Visibility]$iconStreams[$i + $systemTrayToggleOffset]
                Offset     = $i
                Path       = Resolve-KnownFolder $iconPath
            }
        }
    }
}

function Backup-SystemTrayIcon {
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS
        Create a backup of the System Tray Icon configuration (IconStreams).
    .DESCRIPTION
        Create a backup of the System Tray Icon configuration (IconStreams).
    #>

    [CmdletBinding()]
    param ( )

    $registryPath = 'HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\TrayNotify'
    $value = Get-ItemPropertyValue $registryPath -Name IconStreams
    New-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath -Name IconStreams_Backup -Value $value -Force
}

function Restore-SystemTrayIcon {
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS
        Restore an existing backup of the System Tray Icon configuration (IconStreams).
    .DESCRIPTION
        Restore an existing backup of the System Tray Icon configuration (IconStreams).
    #>

    [CmdletBinding()]
    param ( )

    $registryPath = 'HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\TrayNotify'
    $value = Get-ItemPropertyValue $registryPath -Name IconStreams_Backup
    if ($value) {
        Set-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath -Name IconStreams -Value $value
    } else {
        Write-Error 'IconStreams backup does not exist!'
    }
}

function Set-SystemTrayIcon {
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS
        Set system tray icon visibility.
    
    .DESCRIPTION
        Set system tray icon visibility using the IconStreams value in the registry.
    #>

    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ParameterSetName = 'ByPath')]
        [SupportsWildcards()]
        [string]$Path,

        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline, ParameterSetName = 'FromPipeline')]
        [PSTypeName('IconStreamsRecord')]
        [object]$InputObject,

        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [Visibility]$Visibility
    )

    begin {
        $registryPath = 'HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\TrayNotify'
        $systemTrayToggleOffset = 528

        if ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'Path') {
            Get-SystemTrayIcon -Path $Path | Set-SystemTrayIcon -Visibility $Visibility
            return
        }

        $iconStreams = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path $registryPath -Name IconStreams
        $shouldUpdate = $false
    }

    process {
        if ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'ByPath') {
            return
        }

        if ($InputObject.Visibility -ne $Visibility) {
            $shouldUpdate = $true
            $iconStreams[$InputObject.Offset + $systemTrayToggleOffset] = $Visibility.value__
        }
    }

    end {
        if ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'ByPath') {
            return
        }
        if ($shouldUpdate) {
            Set-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath -Name IconStreams -Value $iconStreams
        }
    }
}
```

You can find more PowerShell code on github such as [nodgear/Awesome ManageTray.ps1](https://github.com/nodgear/Awesome/blob/c4ae617e114975e6f8c52fb5656c84a1107ab616/%40Resources/Scripts/Batch/ManageTray.ps1) and [stevencohn/WindowsPowerShell Set-NotifyIcon.ps1](https://github.com/stevencohn/WindowsPowerShell/blob/fd56aec2c8823c7600cba29e38b9913b109fbf9d/Modules/Scripts/Set-NotifyIcon.ps1)

Tim Mintner also has an old 2011 blog post where he [partially reverse engineered the format](https://web.archive.org/web/20221007042903/https://tmintner.wordpress.com/2011/07/08/windows-7-notification-area-automation-falling-back-down-the-binary-registry-rabbit-hole/) of IconStreams

```
HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\TrayNotify
IconStreams
REG_BINARY
20 byte header followed by 
X number of 1640 byte items where X is the number of items that have notification settings. 
Each 1640 byte block is comprised of at least (one of the sections is not fully decoded so it may be made up of 2 or more sections) 5 fixed byte width sections as follows:

- 528 bytes – Path to the executable
- 4 bytes – Notification visibility setting
- 512 bytes – Last visible tooltip
- 592 bytes – Unknown (Seems to have a second tool-tip embedded in it but the starting position in the block changes)
- 4 bytes – ID?
```