# Starting Windows without explorer.exe

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry

I have a PC where I'm only running one application. I would like to prevent explorer.exe from being loaded on startup. I've read that one could change the registry entry in "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" -> Shell"=""
but unfortunately that absolutely doesn't work.

I tried manually to terminate explorer.exe, then replace it with an .exe that does nothing. That solution isn't great because in this case the logon cosumes approx 2-3 minutes (even-though without explorer). I guess there is a timeout period set up somewhere and the logon is using that time to find explorer.exe.
Don't get me wrong: I do not want to remove explorer.exe from my system, I just want to remove it from the startup (logon) sequence. I know that it is possible as I have already seen it. For maintenance purposes one could manually restart explorer.exe via task manager.

Could anyone help me out, please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you just run the application in question maximized and end explorer.exe after the application has started?  In order to be effective you would have to disabled Task Manager.

Comment: Alternatively, you might consider replacing "explorer.exe" in that key with your program instead - but see the comments in https://superuser.com/questions/1016380/how-do-i-replace-the-system-shell-explorer-exe-with-another-process-in-windows regarding the risk of 'bricking' your system.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Unfortunately the option with the registry key doesn't work. I can enter whatever I want in that key, windows ignores it. If it is possible to shut down explorer after startup it should also be possible to stop it from starting.

Comment: Please note this registry key exist two times. One for 32bit and one for 64bit. Only the 64bit key is working. If you start regedit.exe as 32bit you will never see the correct key.

Comment: With the shell key set, run Process Monitor and capture a boot log.  See if the key you have set has been read.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Yes, I set the Winlogon/Shell key to """" in both versions, but windows totally ignores it.
I captured a boot log as suggested but wasn't able to gather more insight :(

Answer (score 1):

Explorer.exe provides basic Windows and desktop functionality. If you kill it while running, it is restarted a few times, and eventually Windows contuinues operating without it - with nothing on the desktop, and no taskbar. If that's what you want, then make a script to kill Explorer a few times, e.g.,

```
taskkill /IM explorerer.exe /F
timeout 5
taskkill /IM explorerer.exe /F
timeout 5
taskkill /IM explorerer.exe /F
timeout 5
taskkill /IM explorerer.exe /F
timeout 5
```

Run the script at startup; it might need Administrator privilege. Not elegant, but usable.

Comment: Hi. Thanks very much! Yes, exactly, I want Windows without Desktop and Taskbar. For maintenance purposes I might launch explorer.exe manually via Task Manager.
I'll give it try.

Comment: BTW, have you looked at Windows Kiosk Mode, https://windowsloop.com/enable-windows-10-kiosk-mode/ ? It also limits the user to a single application.

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply. Unfortunately, kiosk-mode is not suitable for my purposes.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use Windows App Kiosk mode (intended purpose).

Then, this is the correct method for replacing explorer.exe in enterprise kiosk (embedded systems, PoS, ATM, etc.):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/kiosk-shelllauncher
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/enterprise/shell-launcher

Alternatively, there is the group policy setting, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-2000-server/cc975911(v=technet.10)

and there is a registry method using Winlogon script key: [How do I replace the system shell (explorer.exe) with another process in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1016380/#1682568)

These other methods can't run UWP apps, because they rely on explorer.exe desktop functionality.